# Form button not being disabled

Tags: angular

I have a form button that is not being disabled. I am doing a check to see if password match and meet a minimum length. Here is my code

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section>
      <div class="page-container">
        <p class="profile-details">
          Please enter a username and password to create your profile
        </p>
        <form [formGroup]="profileDetailsForm">
          <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" formControlName="username" size="50" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" formControlName="password" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="confirmPassword"
              (ngModelChange)="onCheckPasswordFields()"
              formControlName="confirmPassword"
            />
            <p *ngIf="isConfirmPasswordFails" class="error">
              * Password and Confirm Password do not match, please try again.
            </p>
          </div>
          <button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="passwordsMatch == 'false'">CREATE PROFILE</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>



  onCheckPasswordFields() {
    const passwordField = this.profileDetailsForm.value.password;
    const confirmPasswordField = this.profileDetailsForm.value.confirmPassword;
    if ((passwordField === confirmPasswordField) && (confirmPasswordField.length > 7)) {
      this.passwordsMatch = true;
    } else {
      this.passwordsMatch = false;
    }
  }

  onCreateProfile() {
    this.profileDetails.username = this.profileDetailsForm.get('username').value;
    this.profileDetails.password = this.profileDetailsForm.get('password').value;
    this.profileDetails.confirmPassword = this.profileDetailsForm.get('confirmPassword').value;
    this.create.emit(this.profileDetails);
    localStorage.setItem('userName', this.profileDetails.username)
  }
```

I am not sure what I a missing here. I thought it was because passwordsMatch was not instantiated but I am declaring it `passwordsMatch: boolean = false;`

Please assist.

Comment: just use `[disabled]="passwordsMatch"`

Comment: your property binding issue as per @Sachila just change these `[disabled]="passwordsMatch"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'false' is not a Boolean value. If your variable is boolean, it will automatically bind to [disable] that bool value.

Use this:

```
<button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="!passwordsMatch">CREATE PROFILE</button>
```

Or, if this is a complex condition, you can call to a method like this

```
<button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="!isPasswordsMatch()">CREATE PROFILE</button>

isPasswordsMatch() {
    //More complex code here
    return this.passwordsMatch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` attribute accepts a boolean value, I hope it will help you

```
  <button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="passwordsMatch">CREATE PROFILE</button>
```

Comment: Comparison is supported, the problem here is that he is comparing a boolean to a string `"false"`.

Doing:  `[disabled]="passwordsMatch === false"` is perfectly fine. Although `!passwordsMatch` is what most people would do.

Answer (score 1):

When you use  `passwordsMatch == 'false'` is equivalent to checking `false=="false"` that's why it is not working. You can make make `passwordsMatch==false` which will work , but it is not proper way of doing things when you use boolean you dont need to compare them just use `passwordsMatch` alone. If you want to reverse it, use `!passwordsMatch`.

```
<button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="passwordsMatch">CREATE PROFILE</button>
```

For reversing ,

```
<button (click)="onCreateProfile()" [disabled]="!passwordsMatch">CREATE PROFILE</button>
```